# if cells are null insert syntax

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to check whether major, grade and university in candidates table, are empty, if so then insert in university...Else...
Is my syntax appropriate?

```
$sqlCheck1 = "SELECT `Major`, `Grade`, `University` FROM Candidates WHERE ID='".$_GET["cid"]."'";

                $result5 = mysqli_query($con,$sqlCheck1);


                while($row5 = mysqli_fetch_array($result5)) {

                    $major = $row5['Major'];
                    $grade = $row5['Grade'];
                    $university = $row5['University'];

                if (mysqli_num_rows($result5) == 0) 
        {
           $sql5 = "INSERT INTO `university` (`major`, `degree`, `univ`, `afnumber`) VALUES ('$major','$grade','$university','".$_GET["af"]."')";
            if (mysqli_query($con,$sql5) === TRUE) {
                    } else {
                    echo "Error: " . $sql5 . "<br>" . mysqli_error($con);
                    }

        }
else 
    {
```

Comment: Use a parameterized query, you have SQL injection vulnerabilities

Comment: @AlexK. ok i will..But is the syntax for checking if the cells are empty is appropriate?

Comment: No. Just use one query.

Answer (score 0):

Use the follwing code

```
$sqlCheck1 = "SELECT `Major`, `Grade`, `University` FROM Candidates WHERE ID='".$_GET["cid"]."'";
            $result5 = mysqli_query($con,$sqlCheck1);
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result5) == 0) 
    {
       $sql5 = "INSERT INTO `university` (`major`, `degree`, `univ`, `afnumber`) VALUES ('$major','$grade','$university','".$_GET["af"]."')";
        if (mysqli_query($con,$sql5) === TRUE) {
                } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql5 . "<br>" . mysqli_error($con);
                }

    }
else 
    {
```

Answer (score 0):

well you are saying that if major, grade and university are empty than insert those empty values in university but the question here is why you want to enter those values if they are empty, even if you want to do so along with inserting afnumber using "$_GET["af"]" variable than you can use following code..

```
$sqlCheck1 = "SELECT `Major`, `Grade`, `University` FROM Candidates WHERE ID='".$_GET["cid"]."'";

            $result5 = mysqli_query($con,$sqlCheck1);

            if (mysqli_num_rows($result5) == 0) 
    {
       $sql5 = "INSERT INTO `university` (`afnumber`) VALUES ('".$_GET["af"]."')";
        if (mysqli_query($con,$sql5) === TRUE) {
                } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql5 . "<br>" . mysqli_error($con);
                }

    }
```

its quite short and fulfill the purpose but make sure you have checked null in database for major, grade and univ fields in university table .